# Explicit comparison in c++

Tags: c++, stl

In the given code i don't understand line 5 & 6 clearly, i know it is used to compare the elements and returns true and false.

```
class Person{
    public:
        float age;
        string name;
    bool operator < (const Person& rhs) const { return age<rhs.age}
    bool operator > (const Person& rhs) const { return age>rhs.age}
};

int main(){
    set<Person, std::greater<>> Set = {{30,"Rupesh"}, {25,"Hitesh"}, {22,"Ritesh"}};
    for(const auto& e: Set){
        cout << e.age << " " << e.name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you know that the functions are used for comparison, then what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are comparison operators, and correctly assumed return true or false.

So the `Person` class defines comparison directly on the object. These operators can be used to simply compare objects:

```
int main()
{
    Person p1;
    Person p2;

    //set some ages
    p1.age = 30;
    p2.age = 20;

    bool p1_older_than_p2 = p1 > p2; // calls operator <
    bool p1_younger_than_p2 = p1 < p2; // calls operator >

    std::cout << p1_older_than_p2; // will print 1 (true), since p1 is older than p2
    std::cout << p1_younger_than_p2; // will on the other hand print 0 (false)
}
```

The operators allow for special syntax, otherwise they are like normal (in this case member) methods. You can call them as such as well, i.e. these calls are equivalent: `p1 < p2` <=> `p1.operator<(p2);`. (the picky would note that `p1 < p2` can also resolve to `operator<(p1,p2)` so the equivalence is not mathematically correct.)

As you see, the operators only allow for nice syntax.

Comment: I think, when you say "return" in the last two lines, you mean "print"

Comment: @MarshallClow, thanks, forgot to update some code comments when I created the variables. I updated.

Comment: @iashek, `const` in `const Person& rhs` means that rhs is guaranteed to not be modified in the method. i.e., the age (nor the name) will be different after calling the `operator<`. Similarly, `const` after the parenthesis guarantees that the class object will not change.  The class object is the object you call the member method on. In the example: `p1 < p2` <=> `p1.operator<(p2)` => class object is `p1`.  So the last `const` guarantees that `p1` will not change either `name` or `age`.